# Python 3.3.2 Else: Invalid Syntax

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner Python user and I am trying to figure out where my invalid syntax is, it seems to be caused by else: but I don't know why.

Program (In Progress)

```
print ("__Fight_Master__")
print ("Type start to begin->")
if input() == "start" :
    print ("Loading Game...")
    else:
        print("Ending Game...")
```

-Aron

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the code above is indented as it is in your actual script, then your indentation is incorrect.  Should be.

```
print ("__Fight_Master__")
print ("Type start to begin->")
if input() == "start" :
    print ("Loading Game...")
else:
    print("Ending Game...")
```